# How to disable windows server 2016 automatic updates on GCE

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

We have multiple windows server 2016  running, will automatic updates on. I want to change the Windows Update mode to Manual.

The problem is when instance is created, out software installation fails many times due to running updates installation. I tried to set instance metadata 'disable-agent-updates' to TRUE. But it doesn't seem to be working.
Please help on how to modify windows update mode on creation and start of instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quick answer is you cannot with Google provided Windows images.

You can create a Windows VM, configure as you desire and then create a new image that you use to launch new instances. This will accomplish your goal with some effort. This is standard practice for companies that manage/control patches and updates.

Note: I do not recommend disabling Windows Update from installing security patches on startup unless you understand the implications.